# Help calculating raffle probability: 75/12.5/6.25/6.25

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Let's suppose we're holding an annual raffle event. ****75%** percent** of the obtained money will be donated to an NGO, whilst the remainder will be dispersed among three prizes.

- Prize one: **12.5%** of the money
- Prize two: **6.25%** of the money
- Prize three: **6.25%** of the money

Each raffle ticket is being sold **$5 a pop**.

**300** tickets have been sold.

---

I've tried to come up with an answer: Would the probabilty to win one of the prizes be 3/300?

What if someone buys 2,3 or even 4 tickets?

Comment: If you bought a single ticket, yes.  All of the information about money being donated and how much you win or how much each ticket costs is completely superfluous information that has nothing to do with the question of the probability of winning.  All that matters is "There are 300 tickets sold, 3 of which are winning tickets"

Comment: Re: "*Could you give me a hint on how to calculate the probability of someone who bought 2 or 3 tickets?*" For that you need to clarify what exactly you mean.  If you are asking the probability of winning *at least one* of the prizes, then it is easiest to approach indirectly, looking instead at the probability of having not won on any of the raffle tickets.  The keyword to search for is [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  Don't be intimidated by the scary-sounding name.  buying $k$ tickets $1-\frac{\binom{297}{k}}{\binom{300}{k}}$

Comment: In the second case do you ask about the probability to win *exactly* one prize or *at least* one prize?

Comment: In both cases (I forgot to mention)

Answer (score 1):

Assume you buy $k$ tickets. The number of ways to choose three winning tickets that are *not* in your posession is $\binom{300-k}3$. Therefore the probability that you win at least one prize is:
$$
1-\frac{\binom{300-k}3}{\binom{300}3}.
$$
In the case $k=1$ this reduces to $\frac3{300}$.

PS. The other parameters such as value of the prize or price of a ticket are irrelevant.